# PHP editing Microsoft Word document str_replace and preg_replace don't work

Tags: php, ms-word, preg-replace, str-replace

Assume, I've got MSWord file source.doc with next content "Content of Microsoft Word file".
For example, I'd like to open it via PHP and replace word "Microsoft" to "Openoffice" and save the result into *result.doc*.
Here is the code using `preg_replace`:

```
$content = file_get_contents( SOMEPATH . '/source.doc' );
$new_content = preg_replace( '/Microsoft/i', 'Openoffice', $content );
file_put_contents( SOMEPATH . '/target.doc', $new_content );
```

Or using `str_replace`:

```
$content = file_get_contents( SOMEPATH . '/source.doc' );
$new_content = str_replace( 'Microsoft', 'Openoffice', $content );
file_put_contents( SOMEPATH . '/target.doc', $new_content );
```

None of them doesn't work. Code runs without any exceptions, but *target.doc* is the same as *source.doc*. Replacement not performs.

I've tried a lot of different reciepts, such as regular expression modificators, iconv and so on, but nothing helps.

`var_dump` of `$content` shows raw structure of *source.doc* that is full of unusual characters and as I suppose some of it stops `str_replace` or `preg_replace` scanning. Can't figure out which char is it and what should I do if I'll find it.

`var_dump` of `$new_content` is identical to $content.

Thanks forward for any help!

Comment: MS Word saves its files in a compressed format, so you won't be able to see or edit the contents without decompressing it first. But even if you do that, you'd have to know the details of the file format (there are several), and there's no guarantee that a word on the page is saved as contiguous characters in the file.

Answer (score 13):

If you have a DOCX file you need to replace something in, its basically a zipped up xml archive.
Here's an example on how to replace the word "Microsoft" with "Openoffice" in a DOCX file.

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
//This is the main document in a .docx file.
$fileToModify = 'word/document.xml';
$wordDoc = "Document.docx";

if ($zip->open($wordDoc) === TRUE) {
    //Read contents into memory
    $oldContents = $zip->getFromName($fileToModify);
    //Modify contents:
    $newContents = str_replace('Microsoft', 'Openoffice', $oldContents);
    //Delete the old...
    $zip->deleteName($fileToModify);
    //Write the new...
    $zip->addFromString($fileToModify, $newContents);
    //And write back to the filesystem.
    $return =$zip->close();
    If ($return==TRUE){
        echo "Success!";
    }
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It would be nice if you also added the source as a link to your answer.

Comment: How do you mean? Source code, or a link to some other source?

Comment: Ah, sorry. I misread the answer. I thought you found the answer from google. If that was the case, a link to the source would be a good thing. Anyway, welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: This works great!! But one tip, because this gave me some grief. If you use replace codes as I did (such as {MYVAL} or etc), and it doesn't change...emit the changed contents to the browser and inspect. You'll find tons of xml garbage around your replace codes. Construct your code accordingly.

Comment: how to replace many strings in this scenario? like $newContents1 = str_replace('Microsoft1', 'Openoffice1', $oldContents); $newContents2 = str_replace('Microsoft2', 'Openoffice2', $oldContents);

Comment: @Swarne27 - Just do a replace on the $newContents again. So it'd be like `$newContents = str_replace('Microsoft1', 'Openoffice1', $oldContents); $newContents = str_replace('Microsoft2', 'Openoffice2', $newContents);`

Comment: How can one save into a new file or redirect to download?

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you are looking for :) http://phpword.codeplex.com/ since doc files are not ordinary text files (try opening one with notepad..you'll get my point)

Comment: Just keep in mind that PHPWord project only allows you to open and manipulate DOCX files (compressed openXML format files). It won't work if you need to deal with the older DOC format.

Comment: http://phpword.codeplex.com/ link is broken, not opening in the browser. Thank you.