# use PHP to read find and replace in MS Word file

Tags: php, ms-word, phpword

hello is there a way to read a MS word file with php then find a specific string and replace it ?

Comment: This didn't work? --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6045951/php-editing-microsoft-word-document-str-replace-and-preg-replace-dont-work

Comment: yes, there is a way.

Comment: @coderodour i try with PHPWord but it gives only the posibility to read and write not to replace

Comment: @Joraid yes but the problem is hat i didn t know what is " word/document.xml" exactly